# Printing graphs textually

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

I have an object graph in memory, I have built it using reflection and dynamically connecting the objects. The graph is directed and has no loops.

For debugging purposes I want to print the built graph as text, how can I do that?

My output should be something like:

```
A  
 \  
  - > C -> D  
 /  
B
```

Comment: This really is far too broad: an answer would need to explain [graph layout algorithm(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) (books are written on this topic). And if you're looking for a tool that does this, the question would be off topic on SO.

Comment: You have to show your current code and if there is a problem then it will be easy for the rest to help you. Your question is too broad!

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is difficult to implement. You should [keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), especially since it's only for debugging. I propose this instead:

```
A, B -> C
C -> D
```